# React.js: Component not updating after first time using 2 functions in onChange function, using Context API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I have been trying to create a Home Loan EMI Calculator, using React.js running on Node.js. I have implemented state management using Context API.

To take inputs from the user, three input type range sliders have been implemented, with their own onChange functions as:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import LoanContext from "../../context/loan/loanContext";
const Form = () => {
    const loanContext = useContext(LoanContext);
    const {
        loanAmt,
        tenure,
        interestRate,
        setInterest,
        setTenure,
        setLoanAmt,
        setAllItems,
    } = loanContext;

    return (
        <form>
            <p className='range-field'>
                <label htmlFor='loanAmt' style={{ fontSize: "1rem", color: "#333333" }}>
                    LOAN AMOUNT
                    <span className='right'>
                        <b>
                            <u>₹ {loanAmt}</u>
                        </b>
                    </span>
                </label>

                <input
                    type='range'
                    id='loanAmt'
                    min='100000'
                    max='100000000'
                    step='1'
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        //Setting the loan Amount and all other components
                        setLoanAmt(e.target.value);
                        setAllItems(interestRate, loanAmt, tenure);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }}
                />
                {"₹ 1 Lakh"}
                <span className='right'>{"₹ 10 crore"}</span>
            </p>
            <p className='range-field' style={{ marginTop: "3rem" }}>
                <label htmlFor='tenure' style={{ fontSize: "1rem", color: "#333333" }}>
                    TENURE (YEARS)
                    <span className='right'>
                        <b>
                            <u>{tenure / 12}</u>
                        </b>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input
                    type='range'
                    id='tenure'
                    min='1'
                    max='30'
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        //Setting the tenure and all other components
                        setTenure(e.target.value);

                        setAllItems(interestRate, loanAmt, tenure);

                        e.preventDefault();
                    }}
                    defaultValue='20'
                    wireModel='rangeSlider'
                />
                {"1"}
                <span className='right'>{"30"}</span>
            </p>
            <p className='range-field' style={{ marginTop: "3rem" }}>
                <label
                    htmlFor='interestRate'
                    style={{ fontSize: "1rem", color: "#333333" }}
                >
                    INTEREST RATE (% Per Annum)
                    <span className='right'>
                        <b>
                            <u>{(interestRate * 1200).toFixed(2)} %</u>
                        </b>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input
                    type='range'
                    id='interestRate'
                    min='0'
                    max='15'
                    step='0.05'
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        //Setting the interest Rate and all other components
                        setInterest(e.target.value);

                        setAllItems(interestRate, loanAmt, tenure);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }}
                    defaultValue='15'
                />
                {"0"}
                <span className='right'>{"15"}</span>
            </p>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

The main issue I am facing is that whenever I change any of the inputs, all the elements including Interest Amount, Loan Amount and Total Amount are updated using the state management from Context, but the EMI value show the previous value, before the change. And it updates whenever I change the input again to the previous intended value.

I will be linking my [github repository](https://github.com/sidsipani23/loan-emi-calc), as well as the [live deployed application](https://loan-emi-calc23.netlify.app/) for a clear picture.

Comment: Can you get rid of all the `e.preventDefault();` from your `onChange` methods. I think that you want the default behavior of input.